# Firefox Extension: Get selected text

Tags: javascript, firefox, selection

I am working on a simple Firefox Extension and I want to get the selected text. I tried this:

```
var WordCount = {
    /* ... */
    changeSelected: function() {
        var selectedText = this.getSelection();
        var words = this.countWords(selectedText);
        this.changeStatus(words, " selected");
        //alert(selectedText);
    },
    getSelection: function(e) {
        var focused_window = document.commandDispatcher.focusedWindow;
        var sel_text = focused_window.getSelection();
        return sel_text.toString();    
    }
}
window.addEventListener("select", function(e) { WordCount.changeSelected(); }, false);
```

The Problem is, that I dont get the selection with **document.commandDispatcher.focusedWindow.getSelection()** and I don't know why :(

Comment: element.value.substring(element.selectionStart, element.selectionEnd); worked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is that `document.commandDispatcher.focusedWindow` is going to be pointing to a chrome window, where I suspect you actually want a content window.  Try replacing that with `content.getSelection()`

Comment: I had to notice that I want to get the selected text in a textarea. This only worked with selectionStart and selectionEnd.

Answer (score 1):

This works in firefox javascripting, so should be OK

```
window.getSelection().toString();
```

My guess is that document.commandDispatcher.focusedWindow fails

Answer (score 0):

Is this a normal Firefox extension or is it a JetPack Firefox extension.

In JetPack it would be

```
var doc = jetpack.tabs.focused.contentWindow;
if (doc.wrappedJSObject){ //This just checks if Firefox has put a XPCNativeWrapper around it for security
  win = doc.wrappedJSObject;
}
```

or you can just access the window directly with `window.getSelection()` like dcaunt suggested