# Firefox addon, accessing selection object via javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

the javascript file contains this code:

```
function getSelected(win) {
    sel = win.getSelection();
    alert(sel);
}
```

The browser.xul file contains this:

```
<popup id="contentAreaContextMenu">
  <menuitem id="selection" label="Select text" accesskey="S" 
   oncommand="getSelected(window);"/>
</popup>
```

The alert is blank, why?

Comment: What does the getSelection function look like?

Comment: @Jimmy Shelter, this function belongs to window object...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The window object you are using in the getSelection function is the browser's window, not the document's window. You probably need to use `content` instead:

```
function getSelected() {
    var sel = content.getSelection();
    alert(sel);
}
```

Check this resources for more info:

- [Firefox Extension: Get selected text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138296)
- http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.extensions/browse_thread/thread/2d106d26d8592bff?pli=1 (The Mozilla page that he points to is really useful)